# buttons and labels resetting when scrolling through collection view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view in which each cell possess the ability to be interacted with by the user. Each cell has a `like` button and a `number of likes` label. When the button is pressed, the button should turn cyan, and the label (which holds the number of likes) should increment. This setup currently works. However, when I scroll through the collection view and scroll back, the button reverts to its original color (white) and the label decrements down to its original value. I have heard of an ostensibly helpful method called `prepareForReuse()`, but perhaps I'm not using it correctly. Here is my code:

Here is the array which holds all the cells

```
var objects = [LikableObject]()
```

Here is the class definition for these objects

```
class LikableObject {

  var numOfLikes: Int?
  var isLikedByUser: Bool?

  init(numOfLikes: Int, isLikedByUser: Bool) {
    self.numOfLikes    = numOfLikes
    self.isLikedByUser = isLikedByUser
  }
}
```

Mind you, there is more functionality present in this object, but they are irrelevant for the purposes of this question. One important thing to be noted is that the data for each cell are grabbed using an API. I'm using Alamofire to make requests to an API that will bring back the information for the `numOfLikes` and `isLikedByUser` properties for each cell.

Here is how I load up each cell using the collection view's delegate method:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ObjectCell", for: indexPath) as! ObjectCell
    cell.configureCell(
      isLikedByUser: objects[indexPath.row].isLikedByUser!,
      numOfLikes:    objects[indexPath.row].numOfLikes!,
    )
    return cell
  }
```

The ObjectCell class has these three fields:

```
var isLikedByUser: Bool?
@IBOutlet weak var numOfLikes: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var likeBtn: UIButton!
```

And that `configureCell()` method, which belongs to the cell class, is here:

```
public func configureCell(numOfLikes: Int, isLikedByUser: Bool) {
    self.isLikedByUser   = isLikedByUser
    self.numOfLikes.text = String(numOfLikes)
    if isLikedByUser {
      self.likeBtn.setFATitleColor(color: UIColor.cyan, forState: .normal)
    } else {
      self.likeBtn.setFATitleColor(color: UIColor.white, forState: .normal)
    }
  }
```

And lastly, the `prepareForReuse()` method is here:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    if isLikedByUser! {
      self.likeBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.cyan, for: .normal)
    } else {
      self.likeBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    }
  }
```

This doesn't work. And even if it did, I still don't know a way to keep the `numOfLikes` label from decrementing, or if it should anyway. I'm speculating that a big part of this problem is that I'm not using the `prepareForReuse()` method correctly... Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: are you updating your objects array properly if user press the button ?

Comment: No, that was my first plan. I realized that the array needed to be modified because that is the structure off of which the collection view grabs its data. However, I realized that the cell class has no direct relationship with the array.. This is unfortunate because the methods that handle the behavior which occurs when the like button is clicked are in the cell class, and thus cannot affect the array without extensive rewiring. This rewiring of course, would most likely not be a best practice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently all of this is good , the only missing part is cell reusing , you have to reflect the changes in the number of likes to your model array

```
class ObjectCell:UICollectionViewCell {

   var myObject:LikableObject!
}
```

In `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.myObject = objects[indexPath.row]
```

Now inside cell custom class you have the object reflect any change to it , sure you can use delegate / callback or any observation technique

Comment: Ohhh, so doing that would, in a sense, "link" the cell with the array that holds the likable objects right?

Comment: since **LikableObject** is class reference then yes

Comment: One more question then. Should I make those changes in the `prepareForReuse()` Method? Other's are saying I don't need it. Because the changes are reflecting when I use the `prepareForReuse()` method. The buttons stay their correct color, but the `numOfLikes` label is changing even more frantically than before. Should I implement changes in the `prepareForReuse()`? or somewhere else. `awakeFromNib()` is not the place to put them.. I just get exceptions. Any insight?

Comment: Wait no i figured it out. I was suppose to make the changes in the `configureCell()` method. Thank you so much

Comment: yes, reflect  myObject value inside **configureCell** , **prepareForSegue** only clears it won't reflect anything

Answer (score 1):

`prepareForReuse` is not the place to modify the cell, as the name states, you "only" have to prepare it for reuse. if you changed something (for example `isHidden` property of a view), you just have to change them back to initial state.

What you should do though, you can implement `didSet` for `isLikedByUser` inside the cell, and apply your modifications to likeBtn in there. (this is of-course the fast solution)

Long solution: It's an anti-pattern that your cell has a property named `isLikedByUser`, TableViewCell is a View and in all architectures, Views should be as dumb as they can about business logic. the right way is to apply these modifications in configure-cell method which is implemented in ViewController.

If you feel you'll reuse this cell in different viewControllers a lot, at least defined it by a protocol and talk to your cell through that protocol. This way you'll have a more reusable and maintainable code.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. I'll try moving that method to the view controller

Comment: well that's just an idea that MVC suggests. If you're designing a cell, from my perspective it's ok to have a field named `isLiked` but not `isLikedByUser`. `isLiked` is more like `isHidden`/`isEnabled`... but `isLikedByUser` indicates some logic inside it.

Answer (score 0):

The `prepareForResuse` isn't needed here.

You do need to update the model underlying the tableview.  One way to verify this is with mock data that is pre-liked and see if that data displays properly.